# Performing an advanced search in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, search, finder

Sorry for a rather silly question. Basically I want to do this. Performing an advanced search excluding files not in my home folder. 
([pathfinder](http://www.cocoatech.com/) users, can you do this?). F.e. displaying all my python scripts *located in my home folder* excluding python files on the system.

(I have some scripts saved from the internet. But I can't find them in an easy way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the desktop and press `Cmd-F`. Select your user name at the top.

[image]

It's the same when you press `Cmd-F` while having your home folder open in a Finder window.

[image]

---

This Finder preference (*When performing a search:*) is related:

[image]

Comment: The secund question you answered for me! You are my hero.